# Mutex in RTOSes in this specific situation

Tags: rtos

Consider the following codes:

```
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 First Thread 
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Thread1 (void const *argument) 
{
    for (;;) 
    {
        osMutexWait(mutex, osWaitForever); 
                Thread1_Functions;
        osMutexRelease(mutex);  
    }
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Second Thread  
 *---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void Thread2 (void const *argument) 
{
    for(;;)
    {
        osMutexWait(mutex, osWaitForever);
                Thread2_Functions;
        osMutexRelease(mutex);
    }
}
```

As far as I've noticed from `RTOS's scheduling` ,RTOS assign a specific time to each task and after this time is over,it switches to the other task.
Then in this specific time,inside task's infinite loop ,maybe loop is repeated several times until task's specific time finished.
Assume task is finished in less than of it's time's half,then it has a time to fully run this task once again.
in last line after releasing mutex , then it will achieve mutex before than task2 for second time,Am I true ?
assume timer tick occur when MCU run `Thread1_Functions` for second time,then task2 cant run because mutex owned by task1, RTOS run task 1 again and if timer tick occur every time in the `Thread1_Functions`, then task2 has no chance to running,Am I true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me clear up the scheduling method that you described.  You said, "RTOS assign a specific time to each task and after this time is over, it switches to the other task."  This scheduling method is commonly called "time slicing".  And all RTOS do not necessarily use this method all the time.  Time slicing may be used for tasks that have the same priority (or if the RTOS does not support task priorities).  But if the tasks have different priorities then the scheduler will not use time-slicing and will instead schedule according to task priority.

But let's assume that the two tasks in your example have the same priority and the scheduler is time-slicing.

1. Thread1 runs and gets the mutex.
2. Thread1's time slice expires and the scheduler switches to Thread2.
3. Thread2 attempts to get the mutex but blocks since Thread1 already owns the mutex.
4. The scheduler switches back to Thread1 since Thread2 is blocked.
5. Thread1 releases the mutex.

When the mutex is released, the scheduler should switch to any higher priority task that is waiting for the mutex.  But since Thread2 is the same priority, let's assume the scheduler does not switch and Thread1 continues to run within its time slice.

6. Thread1 attempts to get the mutex again.

In your scenario Thread1 successfully gets the mutex again and this could result in Thread2 never being able to run.  In order to prevent this from happening the mutex service should prioritize requests for the mutex.  Mutex requests from higher priority tasks receive higher priority.  And mutex requests from equal priority tasks should be first come, first served.  In other words, the mutex service should put requests from equal priority tasks into a queue.  Remember Thread2 already has a pending request for the mutex (step 3 above).  So when Thread1 attempts to get the mutex again (step 6), Thread1's request should be queued behind the earlier request from Thread2.  And when Thread1's second request for the mutex get queued behind the request from Thread2, the scheduler should block Thread1 and switch to Thread2, giving the mutex to Thread2.

**Update**: The above is just an idea for how an unspecified RTOS might handle the situation in order to avoid starving Thread2.  You didn't mention a specific RTOS until your comment below.  I don't know whether Keil RTX works like I described above.  And now I'm wondering what your question really is.

Are you asking what will Keil RTX do in this situation?  I'm not sure.  You'll have to look at the code for osMutexRelease() to see whether it switches to a task with the same priority.  Also look at osMutexWait() to see how it prioritizes tasks of the same priority.

Or are you stating the Keil RTX allows Thread2 to starve in this situation and are you asking how to fix it.  To fix this situation you could call osThreadYeild() after releasing the mutex.  Like this:

```
void Thread1 (void const *argument) 
{
    for (;;) 
    {
        osMutexWait(mutex, osWaitForever); 
                Thread1_Functions;
        osMutexRelease(mutex); 
        osThreadYeild();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Assume in the 2th section , time slice expired on the body of the thread 2 !what happens know?I am using KEIL RTX which used pre-emptive round robin time schedling.Each task executed only one time or it runs ever and ever until next timer tick?